# Android OpenGL 2 Scrolling Texture Loses Quality Over Time

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple game for Android, using OpenGL 2 ES, that utilizes a repeating scrolling texture for the background.  I managed to draw the texture, scroll it, and repeat.  It works really well for the first few seconds, then the quality of the image starts to degrade - gets very pixelated.  After about 10 seconds, the scrolling image is just about unrecognizable.

The texture scrolls automatically/infinitely using a float value passed to u_Scroll.

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform float u_Scroll;
uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, vec2(v_TextureCoordinates.x, v_TextureCoordinates.y + u_Scroll));
}
```

Load Texture Method

```
public static int loadBackgroundTexture(Context context, int resourceId) {
    final int [] textureObjectIds = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectIds[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    return textureObjectIds[0];
}
```

onDraw from Renderer:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    multiplyMM(viewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
    invertM(invertedViewProjectionMatrix, 0, viewProjectionMatrix, 0);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    positionBackgroundInScene();
    backgroundProgram.useProgram();
    backgroundProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, texture[1]);
    background.bindData(backgroundProgram);
    background.draw();

    positionAngelInScene(angelPosition.x, angelPosition.y, angelPosition.z);
    textureProgram.useProgram();
    textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, texture[0]);
    angel.bindData(textureProgram);
    angel.draw();

}
```

I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure what other code to post.  Why would my background texture be good at first and degrade over time?  Unfortunately, I don't have a high enough rep to post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're simply incrementing/decrementing the `u_Scroll` value while you scroll, and count on the texture `GL_REPEAT` behavior to give you endless scrolling.

The problem here is most likely floating point precision. A `medium` float value, which is what you're using for the texture coordinate math, has only about 0.1% (10 bits) relative precision in a typical implementation.

To illustrate the implications of this, say you have scrolled through 10 times, and your range of texture coordinates is now between 10.0 and 11.0. At 0.1% relative precision, the increment between floating point values you can represent in this range is about 0.01. Or in other words, you can represent about 100 values between 10.0 and 11.0. If your texture is e.g. 512x512, you can only address every 5th pixel with your texture coordinates.

One option to use this is to change the float precision to `highp`. But that's not guaranteed to be supported on all ES 2.0 implementation.

Unless I misunderstand what you're doing, there should be a very easy solution: Keep the range of the value you use to set `u_Scroll` between 0.0 and 1.0 in your app code.

You probably have code that logically looks something like this in your app code to translate user input to scrolling:

```
if (scrollRight) {
    scrollValue += scrollIncrement;
} else if (scrollLeft) {
    scrollValue -= scrollIncrement;
}
...
glUniform1f(scrollLoc, scrollValue);
```

Change this to:

```
if (scrollRight) {
    scrollValue += scrollIncrement;
    if (scrollValue > 1.0f) {
        scrollValue -= 1.0f;
    }
} else if (scrollLeft) {
    scrollValue -= scrollIncrement;
    if (scrollValue < 0.0f) {
        scrollValue += 1.0f;
    }
}
...
glUniform1f(scrollLoc, scrollValue);
```

This will keep `scrollValue` between 0.0 and 1.0, which allows you to use the full relative precision of the `medium` texture coordinates in your fragment shader.

Comment: This is some great info.  I will give this a try today.  Thank  you.

Comment: Success!  I ended up updating the float precision in the fragment shader to highp.  I should've specified in my post that the scrolling is automated and infinite.   I'm passing a set float value to u_Scroll, as opposed to reading user input.  I assume this meant my only option was to change the precision in the shader.  If so, I will mark this as answer.